# Make tikz nodes touch bottom to top edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, tikz-node

I have two tikz nodes like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\titleheight}{0.25in}
\newcommand{\titlewidth}{2.0in}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\tikzstyle{category}=[draw, fill=yellow!20]
\tikzstyle{title}=[minimum height=\titleheight,minimum width=\titlewidth, text width=\titlewidth, fill=blue!20, text centered,draw=black,line width=0.1mm]
\tikzstyle{summary}=[minimum width=\titlewidth, text width=\titlewidth, text centered,draw=black,line width=0.1mm ]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (1t) [title] {Zomerfeld v. Noto (2012) [1]};
\node (1s) [summary,below of=1t,node distance=0.5in] {Inadmissible evidence can be used to evaluate the admissibility of evidence but that doesn’t make the inadmissible evidence admissible.};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the bottom node (1s) be positioned directly below the top node (1t)? I don't want to hardcode this distance, because the size of the bottom node is variable.

Comment: but lower node is already below top. please clarify, how you like to obtain.

Comment: You are loading the `positioning` library but you are not using it. Try `\node (1s) [summary,below=0pt of 1t,node distance=0.5in] {Inadmissible evidence can be used to evaluate the admissibility of evidence but that doesn’t make the inadmissible evidence admissible.};`. Note the different syntax `,below=0pt of 1t` instead of `below of=1t`. `=` and `of` got swapped, and I added an explicit distance `0pt`. Notice also that you can achieve the same with `shapes.multiparts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451318/make-tikz-nodes-touch-bottom-to-top-edge#comment1134592_451318), you were not using the `positioning` library. Zarko's answer is using that syntax. Anyway, if you want touching nodes, I would suggest to use the `shapes.multipart` library or my code above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newcommand{\titleheight}{0.25in}
\newcommand{\titlewidth}{2.0in}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw,
minimum height=\titleheight,minimum width=\titlewidth, 
text width=\titlewidth, text centered,draw=black,line width=0.1mm,
rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white}]
{\nodepart{one}Zomerfeld v. Noto (2012) [1]
\nodepart{two}Inadmissible evidence can be used to evaluate the admissibility of
evidence but that doesn't make the inadmissible evidence admissible.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]